# How would a study in which a clinical group and a healthy control group both receive the same intervention be classified?

Tags: experiment-design, clinical-trials

I need to classify the design of a study in which 2 groups receive the same intervention and are compared regarding specific outcome parameters (pre-post difference). One group consists of subjects with a mental disorder and the other group is a healthy control group. Would that study count as a clinical controlled trial (although both groups receive the same intervention) or is it a case-series study (although there is a control group)?

Comment: What you’re measuring is the effect of mental health on people who receive this treatment, not the effect of the treatment on people with the mental disorder.

Comment: Isn't it both? The study measures the pre-post difference for each group (which would be the effect of the treatment) and also the if the treatment affects both groups differently (which would be the effect of mental health on people who receive the treatment). 
But do you have an idea how the study could be classified in terms of design (interventional - e.g. CCT, observational - e.g. case-control study, case-series study...)?